# Java Servlet работа с Json

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Недавно начал изучать `servlet`. На данный момент на томкате развернут проект с одной `jsp` страничкой. Есть база данных MySQL.

Не совсем понимаю, как реализовать общение клиента с сервером.

- Правильно ли я понимаю, что, на данный момент, клиентская часть - это `jsp` страничка, а сам сервлет и все остальное - серверная?
- Если это так, то я должен отправлять и принимать на клиенте `json` объекты. Как это правильно делается?

Comment: А, откуда Вы планируете получать JSON и, что с ним Вы планируете делать после получения?

Comment: Json планировал получать от сервера. Приходит мне,,например, список объектов в json. Я на клиенте отображаю эти данные.

Comment: От какого сервера и как отображать? Если данные выдаёт серверная сторона Вашего сайта и Вы хотите их обновлять у клиента без перезагрузки страницы, то это через AJAX. Если Вы хотите обработать, то, что выдаёт API стороннего ресурса, то здесь всё несколько сложнее. В общем, если хотите получить конкретный ответ, внесите больше конкретики в вопрос.

Comment: Под сервером я имел в виду мой код на java. Т.е. я должен со стороны клиента послать json обьект моей серверной части. В этом объекте я прописываю метод и параметры для вызова соответствующего метода на сервере. Сервер в свою очередь посылает мне ответ тоже в виде json. По крайней мере, я так это представлял. Как-то это должно происходить через сервлет.

Comment: Например, мне нужно вывести список пользователей. Я должен получить на клиенте json и с ним уже работать.

Comment: Так это можно сделать и без JSON. Разумеется, что доступ к БД лучше оставить в сервлете, а отображать в JSP. Если хотите делать все манипуляции без перезагрузки страницы, то тогда есть смысл получать данные в виде JSON через AJAX. Тут уже всё зависит от задачи.